# I just wanna update my activity automatically when i insert or delete data in SQLite using FAB button and Delete button

Tags: java, android, sql, xml

and also when I delete any data so it just fills the gap of that data so help me what should I do in my code
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkM5D1WE2N-Qmqm2_DwiyLdnXDNhSSyV/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg1G5.png) this is an image here you can see 12 14 and I delete 13 so why it haven't change and if I use Intent for refresh MainActivity so the data is inserted and delete is changed but when we press the back button it moves to the previous mainActivity and data is lost.

This is **MainActivity** Code

```
 package com.example.booklibrary;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton fltButn;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabsae;
    myDatabaseClass myDatabaseClass;
    ArrayList < String > book__id, book__title, book__author, book__pages;
    customAdapter customAdapter;
    RelativeLayout forsnackbar;
    ImageView empty_image , main_Search ,showoff_Search;
    TextInputLayout search_text;
    TextView empty_textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
        forsnackbar = findViewById ( R.id.main_relative );


        //for emptyIamge View
        empty_image  = findViewById ( R.id.empty_imageView );
        empty_textView =findViewById ( R.id.empty_textView );

        //for search
        main_Search = findViewById ( R.id.main_search );
        search_text =  findViewById ( R.id.search_editText );

        //for showoffSearch
        showoff_Search = findViewById ( R.id.showoff_search );
        showoff_Search.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showoff_Search.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
                main_Search.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                search_text.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
            }
        } );

        //recyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById ( R.id.recyclerView );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( MainActivity.this ) );


        myDatabaseClass = new myDatabaseClass ( MainActivity.this );
        book__id = new ArrayList <> ();
        book__title = new ArrayList <> ();
        book__author = new ArrayList <> ();
        book__pages = new ArrayList <> ();

        //method for showing data into UI
        showDataToUi ();
        customAdapter = new customAdapter ( this , book__id , book__title , book__author , book__pages );
        recyclerView.setAdapter ( customAdapter );
        //floatingAction button
        fltButn = findViewById ( R.id.addFloating );
        fltButn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toast.makeText ( MainActivity.this , "Hello" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                fabButtonClick ();
            }
        } );


    }


    private void fabButtonClick() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder myDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder ( this );
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from ( this );
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate ( R.layout.add_data , null );
        myDialog.setView ( view );
        alertDialog = myDialog.create ();
        alertDialog.setCancelable ( true );


        final TextInputLayout title,author, pages;;
        Button addButton;
        title = view.findViewById ( R.id.Title );
        author = view.findViewById ( R.id.Auther );
        pages = view.findViewById ( R.id.pages );


        addButton = view.findViewById ( R.id.addButton );
        addButton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String bookTitle = title.getEditText ().getText ().toString ().trim ();
                String bookAuthor = author.getEditText ().getText ().toString ().trim ();
                String bookPages =  pages.getEditText ().getText ().toString ().trim () ;

                if(bookTitle.equals ( "" ))
                {
                    title.setError ( "Required Field" );
                }
                else if(bookAuthor.equals ( "" ))
                {
                    author.setError ( "Required Field" );
                }
                else if(bookPages.equals ( "") )
                {
                    pages.setError (  "Required Field");
                }
                else {
                myDatabaseClass myDatabaseClass = new myDatabaseClass ( MainActivity.this );
                myDatabaseClass.addBook ( bookTitle , bookAuthor , bookPages );
                alertDialog.dismiss ();
//                Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext () , MainActivity.class );
//                startActivity ( intent );
                    Snackbar.make ( forsnackbar,"Added",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();

            }
        } });
        alertDialog.show ();
        //.getWindow().setLayout(1200, 900); - this work when we use a simple AlerrtDialog

    }

    private void showDataToUi() {
        Cursor cursor = myDatabaseClass.readAllData ();
        if (cursor.getCount () == 0) {
            Toast.makeText ( this , "No data" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
            empty_textView.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
            empty_image.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
        } else {
            while ((cursor.moveToNext ())) {
                book__id.add ( cursor.getString ( 0 ) ); //here add() function is from ArrayList
                book__title.add ( cursor.getString ( 1 ) );
                book__author.add ( cursor.getString ( 2 ) );
                book__pages.add ( cursor.getString ( 3 ) );
            }
            empty_textView.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
            empty_image.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
        }
    }



}
```

This is **myDatabse** Class

```
package com.example.booklibrary;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class myDatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context context;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookLibrary.DB";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "My_Book";
    public static String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "book_title";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR = "book_author";
    public static final String COLUMN_PAGES = "book_pages";

    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    myDatabaseClass(@Nullable Context context) {
        super ( context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION );
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String query = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_AUTHOR + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PAGES + " INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL ( query );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db , int oldVersion , int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL ( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate ( db );

    }

    //for inserting the data into table
    void addBook(String title , String name , String pages) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase (); //this method in use to write the data to our table
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues (); //it passs the value to our database table
        values.put ( COLUMN_TITLE , title );
        values.put ( COLUMN_AUTHOR , name );
        values.put ( COLUMN_PAGES , pages );
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert ( TABLE_NAME , null , values );

        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText ( context , "failed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText ( context , " success add book" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    }

    //for showing the data to the UI
    Cursor readAllData() {
        String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME ;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase ();
        Cursor cursor= database.query ( TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,COLUMN_ID);
        if (database != null) {
            cursor = database.rawQuery ( query , null );
        }
        return cursor;
    }
//for update the data

    void upadteData(String row_id , String row_title , String row_author , String row_pages) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase ();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues ();
        contentValues.put ( COLUMN_TITLE , row_title );
        contentValues.put ( COLUMN_AUTHOR , row_author );
        contentValues.put ( COLUMN_PAGES , row_pages );

        long result = sqLiteDatabase.update ( TABLE_NAME , contentValues , "_id=?" , new String[]{row_id} );
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText ( context , "Failed update" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText ( context , "update done" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }

    }

    //for delete the data
    void deleteData(String row_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase ();
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.delete ( TABLE_NAME , "_id= ?" , new String[]{row_id} );

        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText ( context , "Failed Delete" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText ( context , "deleted done" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **Adapter** class

```
package com.example.booklibrary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class customAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < customAdapter.MyViewHolder > implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    String delete_id, update_id, update_title, update_author, update_pages;
    Intent intent, inn;
    private Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private ArrayList < String > book__id, book__title, book__author, book__pages;


    public customAdapter(Context context , ArrayList < String > book__id , ArrayList < String > book__title , ArrayList < String > book__author , ArrayList < String > book__pages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.book__id = book__id;
        this.book__title = book__title;
        this.book__author = book__author;
        this.book__pages = book__pages;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent , int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from ( context );
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate ( R.layout.custom_adapter , null );
        return new MyViewHolder ( view );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder , final int position) {
        holder.id.setText ( book__id.get ( position ) );
        holder.title.setText ( book__title.get ( position ) );
        holder.author.setText ( book__author.get ( position ) );
        holder.pages.setText ( book__pages.get ( position ) );

        holder.myLinerLayout.setOnLongClickListener ( new View.OnLongClickListener () {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {



                //for delete the item
                delete_id = book__id.get ( position );
                update_id = book__id.get ( position );
                update_title = book__title.get ( position );
                update_author = book__author.get ( position );
                update_pages = book__pages.get ( position );

                longClickMenu ( v );

                return true;

            }
        } );

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return book__id.size ();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView id, title, author, pages;
        RelativeLayout myLinerLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super ( itemView );

            id = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.item_id );
            title = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.item_title );
            author = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.item_AuthorName );
            pages = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.item_pages );
            myLinerLayout = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.item_linerLayout );


        }

    }

    private void longClickMenu(View view) // View must be pasing
    {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu ( view.getContext () , view );
        popupMenu.inflate ( R.menu.popup_menu );
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener ( customAdapter.this );
        popupMenu.show ();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId ()) {

            case R.id.edit_item:
                //context.startActivity ( intent );
                editButtonClick ();
                return true;

            case R.id.delete_item:
                Toast.makeText ( context , "click delete" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                myDatabaseClass myDatabaseClass = new myDatabaseClass ( context );
                myDatabaseClass.deleteData ( delete_id );
                Intent intent = new Intent ( context , MainActivity.class );
                context.startActivity ( intent );
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }

    }

    private void editButtonClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder ( context );
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from ( context );
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate ( R.layout.add_data , null );
        myDialog.setView ( view );
        alertDialog = myDialog.create ();
        alertDialog.setCancelable ( true );
        final TextInputLayout updateTitle, updateAuthor, updatePages;
        updateTitle = view.findViewById ( R.id.Title );
        updateAuthor = view.findViewById ( R.id.Auther );
        updatePages = view.findViewById ( R.id.pages );
        updateTitle.getEditText ().setText ( update_title );
        updateAuthor.getEditText ().setText ( update_author );
        updatePages.getEditText ().setText ( update_pages );
        Log.d ( "update thing " , update_id );
        Button updatebutton = view.findViewById ( R.id.addButton );
        updatebutton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDatabaseClass myDatabaseClass = new myDatabaseClass ( context );
                myDatabaseClass.upadteData ( update_id , updateTitle.getEditText ().getText ().toString () , updateAuthor.getEditText ().getText ().toString () , updatePages.getEditText ().getText ().toString () );
                inn = new Intent ( context , MainActivity.class );
                context.startActivity ( inn );
            }
        } );
        alertDialog.show ();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [notifyDataSetChanged();](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)

Inside your fab onClick add this

```
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And deleting the rows use

```
book_id.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);                 
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, book_id.size());
```

That's it

Update :

```
            package com.example.booklibrary;

        import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuInflater;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
        import android.widget.SearchView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
        import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
        import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
        import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            RecyclerView recyclerView;
            FloatingActionButton fltButn;
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            SQLiteDatabase mDatabsae;
            myDatabaseClass myDatabaseClass;
            ArrayList < String > book__id, book__title, book__author, book__pages;
            customAdapter customAdapter;
            RelativeLayout forsnackbar;
            ImageView empty_image , main_Search ,showoff_Search;
            TextInputLayout search_text;
            TextView empty_textView;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
                setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
                forsnackbar = findViewById ( R.id.main_relative );


                //for emptyIamge View
                empty_image  = findViewById ( R.id.empty_imageView );
                empty_textView =findViewById ( R.id.empty_textView );

                //for search
                main_Search = findViewById ( R.id.main_search );
                search_text =  findViewById ( R.id.search_editText );

                //for showoffSearch
                showoff_Search = findViewById ( R.id.showoff_search );
                showoff_Search.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showoff_Search.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
                        main_Search.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                        search_text.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                    }
                } );

                //recyclerView
                recyclerView = findViewById ( R.id.recyclerView );
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( MainActivity.this ) );


                myDatabaseClass = new myDatabaseClass ( MainActivity.this );
                book__id = new ArrayList <> ();
                book__title = new ArrayList <> ();
                book__author = new ArrayList <> ();
                book__pages = new ArrayList <> ();

                //method for showing data into UI
                showDataToUi ();
                customAdapter = new customAdapter ( this , book__id , book__title , book__author , book__pages );
                recyclerView.setAdapter ( customAdapter );
                //floatingAction button
                fltButn = findViewById ( R.id.addFloating );
                fltButn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Toast.makeText ( MainActivity.this , "Hello" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                        fabButtonClick ();
                    }
                } );


            }


            private void fabButtonClick() {
                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder myDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder ( this );
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from ( this );
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate ( R.layout.add_data , null );
                myDialog.setView ( view );
                alertDialog = myDialog.create ();
                alertDialog.setCancelable ( true );


                final TextInputLayout title,author, pages;;
                Button addButton;
                title = view.findViewById ( R.id.Title );
                author = view.findViewById ( R.id.Auther );
                pages = view.findViewById ( R.id.pages );


                addButton = view.findViewById ( R.id.addButton );
                addButton.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String bookTitle = title.getEditText ().getText ().toString ().trim ();
                        String bookAuthor = author.getEditText ().getText ().toString ().trim ();
                        String bookPages =  pages.getEditText ().getText ().toString ().trim () ;

                        if(bookTitle.equals ( "" ))
                        {
                            title.setError ( "Required Field" );
                        }
                        else if(bookAuthor.equals ( "" ))
                        {
                            author.setError ( "Required Field" );
                        }
                        else if(bookPages.equals ( "") )
                        {
                            pages.setError (  "Required Field");
                        }
                        else {
                        myDatabaseClass myDatabaseClass = new myDatabaseClass ( MainActivity.this );
                        myDatabaseClass.addBook ( bookTitle , bookAuthor , bookPages );
                        alertDialog.dismiss ();
        //                Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext () , MainActivity.class );
        //                startActivity ( intent );
                            Snackbar.make ( forsnackbar,"Added",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();

                        //Added
                        showDataToUi
                        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                } });
                alertDialog.show ();
                //.getWindow().setLayout(1200, 900); - this work when we use a simple AlerrtDialog

            }

            private void showDataToUi() {
                Cursor cursor = myDatabaseClass.readAllData ();
                if (cursor.getCount () == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText ( this , "No data" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                    empty_textView.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                    empty_image.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                } else {
                    while ((cursor.moveToNext ())) {
                        book__id.add ( cursor.getString ( 0 ) ); //here add() function is from ArrayList
                        book__title.add ( cursor.getString ( 1 ) );
                        book__author.add ( cursor.getString ( 2 ) );
                        book__pages.add ( cursor.getString ( 3 ) );
                    }
                    empty_textView.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
                    empty_image.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
                }
            }



        }
```

Comment: in your adapter on delete_item but you must add position variable on it and also in onBindViewHolder

Comment: but sir i am putting the code in onBindViewHolder but how we set on the delete button? becouse if we add code in onBind so it delete code when we click on item.

Comment: no you can add that code in your delete button, but ensure that int position is provided , you can use global variable and assign it

Comment: sir i am trying but this is not work. how i store position in global var?

Comment: just like update_id variable but make it int and assign it to the position , this.position = position in onBindViewHolder

Comment: sir you can see,here the data is enter again and again [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itGxe3nCSHg1StIz_11hrHAYme4W4CxO/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

@jerson

Here is my Fab button clik code but when we add new data the recyclerView is not changing.

```
 //floatingAction button
        fltButn = findViewById ( R.id.addFloating );
        fltButn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toast.makeText ( MainActivity.this , "Hello" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                fabButtonClick ();
                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } );
```

and Here is my delete button code in adapter class

```
case R.id.delete_item:
                Toast.makeText ( context , "click delete" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                myDatabaseClass myDatabaseClass = new myDatabaseClass ( context );
                myDatabaseClass.deleteData ( delete_id );

                book__id.remove (postionForDelete);
                notifyItemRemoved(postionForDelete);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(postionForDelete, book__id.size());
                notifyDataSetChanged ();
                return true;
```

and this code is paste in onBindViewHolder class ,m storing the postion into  postionForDelete var.But its deleting the other id data.

```
this.postionForDelete =  position;
```